# one line command to execute multiple ssh command

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file which contains host info, one host one line

```
host1
host2
host3
```

what I want to do is

```
ssh host1 'my command' 
ssh host2 'my command' 
ssh host3 'my command'
```

how can I use one line command to implement it (not complex shell script), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this too complex for what you want?

```
for h in $(<file); do ssh $h 'my command'; done
```

Another possibility:

```
cat file | xargs -I% -- ssh % 'my command'
```

or shorter:

```
<file xargs -I% -- ssh % 'my command'
```

or shorter if you are sure you don't have any `-` option in your ssh command:

```
<file xargs -I% ssh % 'my command'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r line; do ssh "$line" 'my command'; done < host
```

The command would read the file line by line, and save each line into the variable `$line`. And execute your ssh command with the host saving in `$line`